# Ask user their last and first name and have an email accout as output

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char last[20];
    char first[20];

    printf("Please enter your last name:");
    scanf("%s",last);
    printf("\nPlease enter your first name:");
    scanf("%s",first);
    printf("Here your email address\n",last,first,@student.com); //last first@student.com

}
```

I want user to write their names and I will output their e-mail automatically.

Comment: printf doesn't work that way.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
printf("Here your email address\n",last,first,@student.com);
```

To:

```
printf("Here your email address: %s%s@student.com\n",last,first);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your last line of code before the end of the program:

```
printf("Here your email address\n",last,first,@student.com); //last first@student.com
```

It looks like you're trying to use `printf` like you're in Python or some other language where you can add strings together and then display them. That's not the way printf works. If you look at the [documentation for printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), in the first parameter you are essentially defining a template for the resulting string. "Hey, I want to print some text, and then here I want to display the results of a string variable, and here I want to display an integer," etc. Then, the rest of the parameters are the variables you want displayed in the string, in the order that you listed them in the first parameter:

```
// NOT WORKING CODE!
printf(template string, var1, var2, ..., varX);
```

When you create the template string, you tell C that you want a variable in a certain place with something called a format specifier. There are a whole bunch of them, and they tell C what kind of variable you're going to have. See the link above for a table showing available format specifiers. In your case, as you're wanting to display a string, the format specifier is `%s`. (Note that the format specifiers are the same as for `scanf`) The last line would then be the following, assuming you want the newline after the email address:

```
printf("Here your email address %s%s@student.com\n",last,first); //last first@student.co
```